# Passport - do EU passports contain information about civil status?

Tags: passports

I have an EU passport. I was married when it was issued. I recently got divorced, but did not change my name. I know that I do not need to get a new passport.

My question is: does the passport contain my civil status information?

Comment: The RFID chip, inside the passport, should not contain that information. German passports and ID don't contain  civil status information.

Comment: Each EU country decides what information its passport contains.  Without knowing what country issued your passport, it's impossible to answer this question.